# Python gives me an error when trying to get anything other than first or last two elements from list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm trying to extract some info out of a .gtf file, which is basically like a type of database where items are tab delimited(or so i'm told). I've written the following simple code to break up each line of the file into a list so each item in the list is one of the "columns" (and also print out the comment lines, but ignore that)

```
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('#'):
        print (line)
line = line.rstrip('\n')
field = line.split()
```

Pretty simple code, and when I put in a print(field) it prints out many lines like this one with varying data

```
['1', 'havana', 'exon', '7962767', '7962875', '.', '+', '.', 'gene_id', '"ENSG00000116288";', 'gene_version', '"12";', 'transcript_id', '"ENST00000497113";', 'transcript_version', '"1";', 'exon_number', '"1";', 'gene_name', '"PARK7";', 'gene_source', '"ensembl_havana";', 'gene_biotype', '"protein_coding";', 'transcript_name', '"PARK7-210";', 'transcript_source', '"havana";', 'transcript_biotype', '"processed_transcript";', 'exon_id', '"ENSE00001935602";', 'exon_version', '"1";', 'transcript_support_level', '"3";']
```

I figure it looks like a list right. So I go to test it with print()

```
print(field[0])
print(field[1])
print(field[-1])
print(field[-2])
```

and those give me this

```
1
havana
"5";
transcript_support_level
```

etc.
So it looks like a list, and acts like a list, but the data I want is in the third column so I just change the code to field[2] and it gives me this

```
   print(field[2])
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I tried putting in different numbers but it's all the same error, and I just really can't figure out why it would let me pull up the first two and last two items in the list, but nothing else? I've tried a lot of things but i'm really just stumped as to what to do here. I can't continue with my code unless I'm able to reference the third column/item in these lists.

Comment: What happens if you call len() on your field?

Comment: check the length of field `len(field)` - there are probably some lines with less fields then you think - f.e. empty lines

Comment: wrap your code in try-except, and print the offending line. That will likely point you in the right direction. (Note, this is the sort of debugging you should probably attempt to do yourself before posting a question, or else people are basically going to ask you to do this anyway)

Comment: The way you wrote your code, the field variable will take only the last line. If your intention is to check all lines, fix the identation. `line.split()` returns a list indeed.

Comment: As said above, check your formatting and don't use the name `file` as a variable. A GTF file is just a simple tab-delimited file with gene information, so there must be something wrong with your code that you are not showing us for it not to work. Post more of your code if you want to get an accurate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I did find a work-around for it with the following code

```
for line in file:
    if line.startswith('#'):
        print (line)
    line = line.rstrip('\n')
    field = line.split("\t")
    for item in field[2:3:1]:
        print(item)
```

It's pretty simple and I probably should have thought of it sooner, but it lets me print out all the items in the third column, so it works but I feel like I just wrote the same thing in different words. Still confused as to why it would only work in a limited fashion the other way though...